# SUM/COUNTIF in excel 2013

Tags: excel, countif, sumifs

I'm having some issues with a formula. In the formula I'm trying to sum the number of items in column E based upon the condition in column C.The formula I've used is, (which is working correctly.)

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!E:E,C86,'Sheet1'!C:C,{"A","B","C","E1","E2","F","G","X","T"}))
```

However in the next cell I'm trying go a bit further and trying to count the number of "Yes" and "NA" in column R based upon the condition in column E and Column C. The formula I've used is -

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!E:E,C86,'Sheet1'!C:C,{"A","B","C","E1","E2","F","G","X","T"},'Sheet1'!R:R,{"Yes","NA"}))
```

This time the formula is counting only "A" in column C and "Yes" in column R. It'll be great help if someone can point  what mistake I'm making with this formula.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

gmainak

Answer (score 0):

Change `'Sheet1'!R:R,{"Yes","NA"}` to `'Sheet1'!R:R,{"Yes";"NA"}`

You can only do two arrays and one needs to be vertical `;` and the other horizontal `,`:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!E:E,C86,'Sheet1'!C:C,{"A","B","C","E1","E2","F","G","X","T"},'Sheet1'!R:R,{"Yes";"NA"}))
```